# Plotly Visuals - Disappearing

Tags: python, plotly

Everytime i open my saved jupyter notebook, all the plots of plotly, disappears. How to fix this issue?

```
fig = px.bar(Current_Employees, x='Date', y='Count',
            hover_data=['Count'], color='Count',
            )

fig.update_traces(text=Current_Employees['Count'], textposition='outside')

fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor = "white",
                        title = dict(text = "Year on Year increase in number of employees"),
                        xaxis = dict(title = "Year  -------------->"), 
                        yaxis = dict(title = "Total number of employees ------------->",
                                    )) 
fig.show()
```

Comment: If you have sample data, we may be able to help.

Comment: The data could be anything, but irrespective of that when you open the same notebook again, plots by plotly donot appear, unless you run all the cells again from the top

Comment: I don't think plotly is the cause of the problem; it may improve if you try to bring your notebook environment up to date. Also, you can see if the graph is saved with the appropriate file size.